# Jobs messages not showing up in global inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, global-inbox

I received a message today from an employer via Stack Overflow Jobs. I got an email about it, and the message appears in the Jobs tab. However, Jobs messages used to appear in my global inbox on Stack Overflow, and this one isn't there even though I suspect it's supposed to be.

Here's my messages accessed via the Jobs tab, showing a message from today:

[image: messages tab in Jobs]

And here's my global inbox, which doesn't have the message from Jobs:
[image: global inbox missing Jobs message]

Comment: Thanks, we're looking into this! Stay tuned...

Comment: We fixed the immediate problem, so new messages will now be delivered to the candidate's global inbox again. We're now investigating how to recover lost global inbox messages for all users.

Comment: I have this issue now (2021). Is there still an issue?

Comment: @bytecode77 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411493

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone back and sent out notifications for messages that didn't get them before, except in the case that the message has already been read.

The original problem (and correct me if I'm wrong, @Max) was that we missed the code that checked whether to send out a global inbox notification when transitioning from CVs to Dev Stories. That was fixed earlier today, and now all the missing notifications have been sent out, if they're still needed.