# Job messages not displayed

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

When I open my personal message box on Stack Overflow I get a blank list, even if I have many messages.

As you can see in the screenshot below, in the dropdown there are two job messages but I cannot see them in the message page of my personal section: the message page is blank.

[image: Screenshot of the bug]

Do you have the same problem?

I think it might be a bug in the JavaScript code. When I open the browser console I get this error:
`Uncaught Couldn't find args for module "Content/Ts/analytics.prizm.ts". Did you forget to call @JavaScript.Module?`

Maybe that exception (related to an analytics library) breaks the other page elements.

Comment: I have the same kind of bug.
It happens for me on Ubuntu + Chrome, MacOS Big Sur+ Chrome and MacOs Firefox.
I get the notification in email so I can see the content of the message but the personal message page as show is blank

Comment: I tried on all my PCs and the messages are not shown in all OS and browsers: on Mac not working on Firefox, Safari and Chrome. On Ubuntu not working on Firefox and Chrome. On Windows not working on Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! We’re doing some JS refactoring (setting up Webpack and modules) and looks like the messages page slipped through the net. (It's slightly different than everything else, naturally.) Should be fixed now.